# MLA Citation & In-Text Citation on LaTeX

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex, mla-style

For my work, I need to use an MLA format for citations. I want to use the (Author, Year) format for the in-text citation, but I do not know how. Can someone help me?

Comment: As far as I know, MLA is not an author-year citation style. MLA only uses the author name in citations (if you cite only one work by the author) and adds the title if required to disambiguate. [`biblatex-mla`](https://ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-mla) implements MLA citations in `biblatex`. But if you want an author-year style, just go with `style=authoryear,`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As moewe told you, MLA citation style is not (Author, Year) but, if you like, you can mix the styles and use `authoryear` for citations and `mla` for bibliography (I don't know if such a thing is orthodox):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[citestyle=authoryear,bibstyle=mla]{biblatex}
\renewcommand{\nameyeardelim}{\addcomma\addspace}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Some examples:

with \verb|\parencite|: \parencite{pines}

with \verb|\textcite|: \textcite{knuth:ct:a}

with \verb|\cite|: \cite{sigfridsson}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much!! This is exactly what I wanted!!

Comment: I accepted it! Thank you so much!

Comment: @observer_meow Thank you for accepting my answer!